# How to see all resources in a google cloud project - from a web browser?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Background: I am coming from Azure cloud where I could see all resources in a project (resource group) by simply navigating to the resource group in https://portal.azure.com from a web browser.

Question: In GCP, I am shown an overview page when I navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=abc-def-ghi. I like to see all resources in this project from a web browser? Is it possible?

[image: azure]


[image: gcp]

Comment: please keep in mind that Azure and GCP are 2 different cloud providers with different architecture. About GCP architecture you can read in [Listing all resources in your hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources). Answer provided by `@guillaume blaquiere` about `Asset Inventory` is most similar to your expectations.

Comment: Even for different architectures, the view could be same. True, maybe if I started with GCP, I would never have asked for this view.

Comment: I think the project view is a good idea. However, how do you display a project with hundreds/thousands of resources which is typical in enterprises? In Azure, once you have a few dozen resources, their view has too much information to be useful. Google Cloud and Azure approach the problem differently. Asset Inventory is one method. There are third-party tools that visualize projects. +1 goes to Azure as it is easier to list everything, +1 goes to GCP as it is easier to get and export details.

Comment: In azure view, even with large number of resource, there are easy filters with resource type. For e.g. during development, we will need to delete resources which we create (or somebody else in team might have left them after creation). I cannot do with with Asset Inventory - since asset type is not an exact match to the asset created. It is some kind of low level detail (e.g. for artifact registry) in GCP. Also Asset Inventory does not provide direct links (or checkbox as in Azure) to delete the resource. Maybe I will get used to this and feel this is better later.

Comment: In particular, I wonder how to get an overview of Cloud SQL instances with database type (postgres, mssql, ...) and machine type or cpus/memory attached. I didn't figure out how to do that, yet.

Comment: Ha! To answer my own question, and maybe you wondered that yourself, you can also get this data from a billing export (e.g., to BigQuery), columns "system_labels".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview) feature. You have that kind of UI

[image]

And also work by API, and you can export your assets to BigQuery to track the changes, evolutions, history,....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that did not help.For e.g If I created a project with a cloud function and cloud run, how do I see them in this view ? In Azure, the resource group view, shows all resources with navigatable links to each resource.

Comment: Click on the resource tab (upper left corner) select the resource type that you want (left-hand side bar), and you will have a tabular list, as you expect. Play with that tool, it solves a lot of challenges

Comment: Thanks. Upvoting. But not marking as answer. For e.g. I like to see how many artifact registries I have in this project - all i can see in asset inventory is artifactregistry.Dockerimage type which is too much noise listing all docker images ever uploaded. Ofcourse, I can goback to CI/CD->Artifact Registry - but that does not give a birds eye view of resources in a project. Maybe that kind of view is not needed at all when working with GCP. Hopefully I will get used to this. :(

Comment: @kiranpradeep , the closest concept to a resource group in GCP is a "project" (and a "folder" is a group of projects).  In concept, it is quite similar, but you're right that access to the resources is not _nearly_ as easy.  I really enjoy GCP -- more so than AWS or Azure, and I've worked with all 3 extensively -- but Azure is certainly the most user-friendly, with the best interface, and does the best job of simplifying the job of understanding what you have.  But GCP tools are just way better... ;-p